# Single or parent/child Page Publishing Flow(s) for multiple SharePoint lists

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

I am very new to Power Automate so please bear with me.

I have a situation where I have a large number of SharePoint sites that use the same basic template and need to have a publishing workflow for approval of Site Page changes. I don't want to have to recreate the publishing workflow over and over again if I don't have to as that will become a maintenance nightmare.

Is there any way to create a publishing workflow that can be used with Power Automate? I would even be happy with a solution where I could create a simple flow for each site that just passes the details of the submitted page to a master flow that does the approval processing.

The Microsoft site says "Reusable Flows - Using some modular thinking, you can create a master flow which a flow per list or library can call to do the heavy lifting." but I have yet to find a decent example of this that doesn't use either the premium HTTP connector or a Solution, which can't be used for a Page Publishing approval.

Answer (score 0):

For SharePoint Online modern sites, we can now configure page approval flow directly with one click. You can check the doc [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/configure-page-approval-using-power-automate-14ce6976-a0a7-427b-b4ab-d28d344a5222).

It is a most basic publishing approval workflow, user need to click on the button to send the approval before publishing. When the approval accepted, the page get published.

And the flow is listed in the power automate studio. You can customize it depend on your needs

[image]

One more thing to mention, We cannot make a flow to handle different lists/library. Simply we need to create separate approval flow for each list/library. I guess you are talking about this [blog](http://johnliu.net/blog/2019/3/one-flow-to-handle-them-all-how-to-subscribe-to-multiple-sharepoint-lists-with-one-flow). And yes, this is the only option I know to make a flow to handle multiple lists.